# Hiding Application Icon programmatically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want user to choose if he want to hide the application icon. If user Hide the application Icon and then force close the application from settings->manage application then my application would not work and there is no way for user to  launch it again as he hide the icon. Is there any solution to this situation?